# Structr drag-n-drop shared component fails

Tags: neo4j, structr

structr (2.0.0 and 2.0.1) - drag-n-drop component from project to shared component fails. Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit), java version "1.8.0_20".

Selects in the Pages Tree View, visible dragging across the page but then disappears with release of the mouse button. Attempting to work the demo project, moving the head element to shared components.

Other components and components from the Welcome page fail as well.

Just in case, three warnings from the server log:

```
17:08:18.051 [main] WARN  o.s.n.StructrWrappingNeoServerBootstrapper - The specified file for server configuration [/etc/neo] does not exist. Using the default non-user-defined server configuration.
17:08:18.057 [main] WARN  o.s.n.StructrWrappingNeoServerBootstrapper - No database tuning file explicitly set, defaulting to [/etc/neo4j.properties]
17:08:18.057 [main] WARN  o.s.n.StructrWrappingNeoServerBootstrapper - The specified file for database performance tuning properties [/etc/neo4j.properties] does not exist.
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Missed a subtlety in the documentation. Selecting the element means pointing to any non-icon part of the element bar, then drag-n-drop. (This was after a careful re-install of the latest Java.)

See Step 16 of https://support.structr.com/article/232, which doesn't mention the significance of the mouse pointer location.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We added a comment to the docs and linked here, see https://support.structr.com/article/238